# "no rules expected the token `<`" when passing a type as an ident to macro_rules

Tags: rust

Toy example:

```
macro_rules! boo {
    ($T:ident) => {
        let x: $T;
    };
}

fn main() {
    boo!(i32);         // WORKS
    boo!(Option<i32>); // PROBLEM
}
```

`boo!(Option<i32>);` causes the error:

```
error: no rules expected the token `<`
 --> src/main.rs:9:16
  |
9 |     boo!(Option<i32>);
  |                ^
```

I can work around it with:

```
type Opti32 = Option<i32>;
boo!(Opti32);
```

But it is too boring to add an alias for every usage of macros.
Is it possible to use macros like `boo!(Option<i32>);` and hide
the difficulty inside `macro_rules`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$T:ident` can only match an `ident`ifier.

If you want `$T` to match any *type*, even if it's not a single identifier, you should use `$T:ty` instead:

```
macro_rules! boo {
    ($T:ty) => {
        let x: $T;
    }
}
```

`ident` and `ty` are called "fragment specifiers" because they specify what kind of code fragment the metavariable `$T` can match. The first edition of the Rust book has [a chapter on macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/macros.html), including a list of possible fragment specifiers; you should definitely familiarize yourself with the contents of this chapter before trying to write a macro.

Comment: Here's a link to the Macros chapter from [the current version of the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html)